# Converting dataframe to timeseries in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time-series, global

There is a dataframe in the `fPortfolio` package  called `SPISECTOR.RET`. I want my dataframe [`df`] to have the same format (`global environment`) as the dataframe [`SPISECTOR.RET`]. My `df` is currently a  `data.frame` of `6 obs. of 3 variables`. I want it in `values` as a `timeSeries` with a description of `Formal Class timeSeries`. I have dput for `df` attached below.

```
library('fPortfolio')
data = SPISECTOR.RET
data(head)
```

Below is what I tried to do by changing the date. however an error occured:`Error in xts(df, as.Date(colnames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y")) :  NROW(x) must match length(order.by)`

```
library(xts)
stocks <- xts(df, as.Date(colnames(df), format='%m/%d/%Y'))
```

---

dput(df):

```
structure(list(ACWI = c(10795L, 10763L, 10768L, 10907L, 10761L, 
10905L), GLD = c(4811L, 4819L, 4853L, 4899L, 4924L, 4882L), TLT = c(615.88, 
615.13, 614.5, 617.38, 619.63, 628.63)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("09/12/2019", 
"10/12/2019", "11/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "13/12/2019", "16/12/2019"
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(xts)
stocks <- xts(df, as.Date(rownames(df), '%d/%m/%Y'))

#            ACWI  GLD TLT
#2019-12-09 10795 4811 616
#2019-12-10 10763 4819 615
#2019-12-11 10768 4853 614
#2019-12-12 10907 4899 617
#2019-12-13 10761 4924 620
#2019-12-16 10905 4882 629
```

Answer (score 2):

You may  have mixed up `colnames` for `rownames`.  It looks like the dates are in "day-month-year" format as well.  This should work:

```
library(xts)

my_xts <- xts(my_df, 
              as.Date(rownames(my_df),
                      format = "%d/%m/%Y"))

 head(my_xts)

            ACWI  GLD    TLT
2019-12-09 10795 4811 615.88
2019-12-10 10763 4819 615.13
2019-12-11 10768 4853 614.50
2019-12-12 10907 4899 617.38
2019-12-13 10761 4924 619.63
2019-12-16 10905 4882 628.63
```